# Закрытие самоответов по причине «Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии ...»

Tags: поддержка, самоответы

Разве данная причина закрытия:

> "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"

может быть применена к вопросом-самоответам?

Кажется что не может, но один [мой вопрос-самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758495/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5) закрыли по этой причине.

Вопрос закрыли после моей небольшой его правки. Насколько я понимаю он попал в очередь на закрытие, при этом участники, голосовавшие за закрытие, почти наверно не знали, что это самоответ (если не знать что это самоответ, то такая причина закрытия вполне подходит).

Comment: Да вообще так себе причина, хотя и получше предыдущей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте больше деталей в ваш вопрос. Например, какой именно вопрос, как это произошло (до публикации ответа, через год после публикации вопроса) и т.д.

Comment: С высокой вероятностью его опять откроют, но если не добавятся детали, с такой же вероятностью могут и закрыть вновь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если решили, что домашние задания закрываем, то однозначно закрываем всегда, не важно самоответ или нет. Это вопрос контроля качества, а не проверки чьих-то усилий. Другое дело, что данная причина закрытия должна применяться только к тем вопросам, которые действительно являются домашними заданиями, т.е. когда текст вопроса состоит из точной копии текста задания с конкретными числами входных параметров, искусственными ограничениями и т.п. "Вывести цифры числа в обратном порядке на С++" - не домашка, это просто очень простой и малополезный на практике вопрос. Нет смысла закрывать вопрос только из-за этого, даже если в нем не было самоответа, поэтому я проголосовал за переоткрытие.

Тем не менее, если вы хотите делится знаниями в виде самоответов, пожалуйста, сфокусируйтесь на чем нибудь уровнем повыше.