# Закрытие учебных вопросов при наличии адекватных ответов

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Пример [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007918/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8). По сути - вопрос не соответствует правилам сайта и он должен быть закрыт, потому что это учебная задача.

Но при этом мы видим, что на вопрос уже дан правильный ответ, который в будущем может быть кому-то полезен.

Мне кажется - не совсем адекватно подобные вопросы закрывать только за качество самого вопроса, не учитывая того, что кто-то тратил свое время и писал ответ.

Comment: Да удалить уже эту причину!

Comment: Какой смысл от учебного задания, если в нем даже проблема не озвучена, с которой столкнулся участник сообщества?

Comment: @РустамГимранов озвучена. Автор не может подсчитать количество слов и вывести в указанном формате.

Comment: @Qwertiy полехче (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007895/256824) участник не может, а в вашем примере вроде бы только изложение о том, что требуется. В целом-то я согласен: вопрос с хорошим ответом не должен быть закрыт.

Comment: Я думаю, под "проблема не озвучена" имеется в виду, что автор не показал, с чем именно у него затруднения. Просто наличие поставленной задачи не является "проблемой". Но тем не менее, данный вопрос, хоть и выглядит домашкой, на самом деле таковой не является, в том смысле, что подсчет числа слов - это вполне практическая задача. Видимо, надо переоткрывать.

Comment: Тем более, что вопрос с полезным ответом можно использовать как заглушку для закрытия других учебных заданий )))

Comment: А почему только "при наличии адекватных ответов"? Как тогда быть в ситуации, когда кто-то успел написать ответ, но не успел его отправить?

Comment: @PashaPash об этом я тоже думал. Но этот момент решается только удалением причины.

Comment: @РашенБеар я тогда буду закрывать как "непонятна суть вопроса"   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Suvitruf думаю, что эта метка создана для других целей. Например когда автор вопроса в пятницу вечером ставится по вене, пишет сюда трип-репорт и ставит метки `php` `mysql`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Закрытие самоответов по причине «Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии ...»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8845/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-

Answer (score -9):

> Мне кажется - не совсем адекватно подобные вопросы закрывать только за
>   качество самого вопроса, не учитывая того, что кто-то тратил свое
>   время и писал ответ.

Почему же не "учитывая"? Очень даже учитываем то, что отвечающий на учебные вопросы не удосужился узнать, что подобные вопросы здесь не приветствуются, ибо даже в причинах для закрытия имеется это упоминания про "учебные вопросы". Так что довод про время отвечающего мимо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99925/discussion-on-answer-by-edem-------).